# Is having a reference to this for easy scoping a good or bad idea?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I sometimes assign the this pointer to a var. The benefit of it is that I don't loose the scope in anonymous callback functions. Is that a good or bad idea?

Example:

```
var Foo = (function($) {
  var Foo = function() {
    var self;

    self = this;

    this.init = function() {
      $('#foo').click(function(e) {
        self.onClick();
      });
    };

    this.onClick = function() {
      console.log(this);
    };

    this.init();
  };

  return function() {
    return new Foo();
  };
})(jQuery);
```

Thank you!
{Jim}

Comment: I don't know whether or not it's a good idea, but I do it all the time.

Comment: This is helpful in cases we have to go thru other functions or iterative processes as we may lose the scope

Answer (score 3):

If you need a reference to the `this` value of a containing scope (which is certainly a reasonable requirement), it must be a good idea, particularly in cases where you are not in control of the function call (such as event handler functions) where it's your only option.

Comment: Yes, but *why* is `this` different than a property/variable wrt. scopes?

Comment: @pst: Are you asking me to explain how `this` works? I'm not sure it needs explaining: the question shows the OP understands it well enough to know that `this` within a nested function is not necessarily the same as the value of `this` in its containing scope.

Answer (score 1):

It's neither a good nor a bad idea. It's your only chance to keep a reference to an **outer scope/context**.

---

I was asked for more detail, here we go:

A `this` value is a special object which is related with the `execution context`. Therefore, you could say it is a context object (an object in which context the execution context is activated).

- In the global context, `this` is the global object itself.
- In case of a function context, `this` in every single function call may be different.
  `this` is determined on entering the context, and in case with a function code the value can be absolutely different every time.

And even <strike>this</strike> that is a **very** brief summary of the whole topic. But you hopefully understand why you need to store a reference for the `this value` to access it from another function context.

Comment: `this` doesn't refer to a "scope", except perhaps in the top-level context. I have given a +1, but I expect a revise which includes the "dynamic" nature of `this` :P

Answer (score 1):

It's not a *bad* idea.  Whether or not it is a *good* idea is mostly stylistic.

An alternate way to write your code is to hold a reference to the `onClick` function in the closure.  However, `this` won't be bound for the `onClick` function when calling it this way.  For example:

```
var Foo = (function($) {
  var Foo = function() {
    this.init = function() {
      $('#foo').click(function(e) {
        onClick();
      });
    };

    var self = this;  // Or use ES5's Function.prototype.bind

    var onClick = this.onClick = function() {
      console.log(self);
    };

    this.init();
  };

  return function() {
    return new Foo();
  };
})(jQuery);
```

I prefer this style to using `self` (or `that` or whatever name you chose) if the object's methods are all in a closure (as in your case).

Comment: This just looks likes another closured variable is being used. But the functional use of a closure around `this` remains.

Comment: @pst, That is correct.  The goal with this pattern is to replace the use of `this` with something more elegant in the language (closures).

Answer (score 1):

There's nothing wrong with doing it that way, except perhaps that you'd have to come up with more synonyms for "this" and "self" if your scope nesting gets deeper than one level. My preferred method for hanging onto a particular "this" value is to use [Function.prototype.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), which is part of the ECMAScript 5 spec and being implemented in browsers now. As of this moment, only Google Chrome supports it natively, to my knowledge, but it's easy to stick it in with a polyfill, as I've been doing for some time.

Comment: I agree, also jQuery and most frameworks emulate bind. There's also a snippet on MDC to recreate bind in most browsers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the only way to retain a reference to the scope.  But don't do this (from your example):

```
var self;
self = this;
```

Instead combine them into one line:

```
var self = this;
```

Comment: but am I wrong that the compiler puts the "var self;" on top again?

Comment: @Jim: There's nothing inherently wrong with `var self; self = this;`, although there's no reason not to shorten it to `var self = this;`. In fact, if it's the first statement within a function (as it is in the question), `var self; self = this;` is effectively what happens when the code executes: the `self` variable is created and initialized with a value of `undefined` in the *variable instantiation* phase, which happens before any statements are actually executed. This happens at run time rather than compile time.